# how to get the cart values when we switch to other view in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I am developing  a shopping cart project.

It has different categories.

Each category has different products.

When I add a product to cart from a particular category it is added.

When I go back and add the another product to the cart in the same category it is added properly and the previous product is also displaying well.

But when go to another category and add product a cart, the cart page is clearing all the previous products and it is not displaying any previous products.

How to resolve this issue and maintain the products that are added in the cart without clearing in the entire project.

I am not using any service to maintain it and I want to maintain it in the angularjs only

Answer (score 1):

There are only 2 ways to keep data across all the angular application within the angular digest cycle.

```
    1--$rootScope(not recommended)
    2--using Angular Services
```

because of your comment am infering when you say
"I am not using any service to maintain it and I want to maintain it in the angularjs only"
you are reffering to 3rd party or backend service. Angular has its own set of services you cuold also use, ie cookies service, storage service or you could roll your own shipping cart service, which is what would advice, building your shopping card service which handles all your operations and keeps track of your data. Angular services are singleton objects for your application which allows them to persist data. creating services is really simple you can just say

```
app.service('myservice',['$rootScope','$http','$timeout',function($rootScope,$http,$timeout){
    //$rootscope useful if you want to broadcast events to the app
    //$http useful if you want to update based on the users selection or deletion
    //$timeout useful if you want to set time based alerts or expirations
    var storage={};
    return{
       insert:function(item){/*logic to insert an item into storage*/},
       remove:function(id){/*logic to remove an item from storage*/},
       get:function(id){/*logic to get all items*/}
    }
}])
```

## A CONTROLLER USING THE SERVICE

```
app.Controller('Category1ItemsController',['myservice',function(myservice){
        $scope.items=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
        $scope.appendItem=function(item){
             myservice.insert(item);
        }
}]);
```

## A VIEW USING THE CONTROLLER

```
<ul ng-controller="Category1ItemsController">
  <li ng-repeat="item in items">
     {{item}}
     <button ng-click="appendItem(item)">Add</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

something like this might give you some clarity. what generator/template project are you using?

Comment: Hi Dayan, thanks for the information. I am just started learning angular js. Can you please provide a sample app with the service to understand it completely